# Why my User Registration Page Gives 'The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.' Error?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to create a user registration form in django by following django tutorial part 15. However, here's an error that is on my way.
My views.py is

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/polls')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'polls/reg_form.html', args)
```

And, it is giving an error.

```
The view polls.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: If the `request.method` is not `'POST'`, then the function will return `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Because your conditional only checks for `POST` request, and `GET` request returns `None` by default as no return value is specified `if request.method != 'POST'`.

Your code indentation is wrong, I assume, it should be:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/polls')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'polls/reg_form.html', args)
```

Also, `None` is being returned if invalid form is `POST`'ed. To resolve that you could simply do this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/polls')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    # These lines will be executed if the request method is not POST or form is invalid
    args = {'form': form} 
    return render(request, 'polls/reg_form.html', args)
```

Comment: This can still return in `None` if the form is not valid.

Comment: Yep, I indicated that but I don't know how @arpan mahatra wants to handle that

Comment: The last two lines should be unindented one level so that they are always run; that way, the form is displayed both on first GET and on invalid POST.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the suggestion, however, in that case the logic to handle invalid form is skipped. I will add this option in the answer though.

Comment: No it isn't, that is exactly how you handle invalid forms: by returning the form to the template and displaying validation errors there.